# Imported views from other site that didn't have any Master display in the UI. How to remove Master display from Views UI?

Tags: 7, views

I wanted to reuse some View I built on older site which is using EVA module and contextual filters and so on. So I just re-imported it to my new site and now from nowhere there's that Master display showing up (while on older site its not shown) when editing view and the view cannot be saved because it gives me error:

```
'Display "Master" uses fields but there are none defined for it or all are excluded.'
```

The problem is that I don't need that master display at all. How is that it popped up from nowhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view will always have a master display. You can set it to not display on the views settings page at 'admin/structure/views/settings'. To get rid of the error you are seeing, just a add field to the master display, or set the display to show content instead of fields.

Comment: That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The master display is what used to be called "default" in previous versions of Views. Sounds like there are some conflicts in its settings. You can change how it's set up by going to admin/structure/views/view/MYVIEW/edit/default where MYVIEW is the machine name of your view.